# Unable to click on checkbox using selenium python. Used ID, XPATH, CLASS but couldnt succeeded

Tags: python, selenium

```
`<label for="f131111" class="checkbox-base pull-left">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="f131111" name="privilegeClubNotifyTerms3">
                        <span class="checkbox-base-text">
                            <span class="text-hide" tabindex="0">Checkbox</span>
                            <p>I agree to receiving marketing communications, offers, news and market research from time to time by electronic media and SMS from Privilege Club. Electronic media refers to email and Social Media.</p>

                        </span>
                    </label>
```

[https://www.qatarairways.com/en-ae/Privilege-Club/join-now.html`](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-ae/Privilege-Club/join-now.html%60)

Comment: Can you shared your code what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can click on the `checkbox` using `JS executor` since the `checkbox is implemented as a before element` [image]

Refer Image

Your solution would look like

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get('https://www.qatarairways.com/en/Privilege-Club/join-now.html')
# Accept Cookies
driver.find_element(By.ID, "cookie-close-accept-all").click()
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 
"cookie-close-accept-all")))
# Scroll to Checkbox
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView()", 
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='f131111']"))
# Click Checkbox
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 
"//input[@id='f131111']/following-sibling::span"))
```

Comment: Hi @paul can you check the above approach